# When trying to display a chart using ChartIt, Error saying template does not exist arises

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I am using [ChartIt](https://github.com/pgollakota/django-chartit) and keep receiving the "Template does not exist" when trying to view the chart at the URL. The tutorial is being followed properly, but may have made a mistake somewhere. I am new to Django, so any help would be appreciated. The request to load the chart is working as the def is being called.

def in the views.py file.

```
def lineChart(request):
    commitData = \
        DataPool(
            series=
            [{'options': {
                'source': TestCommit.objects.all()[:200]}, 'terms': ['author', 'author_time']}])

    linechart = Chart(
        datasource=commitData,
        series_options=
        [{'options': {
            'type': 'line',
            'stacking': False},
          'terms': {
              'author_time': [
                  'author_time']
          }}],
        chart_options=
        {'title': {
            'text': 'YAYs'},
         'xAxis': {
             'title': {
                 'text': 'Month number'}}})


    return render_to_response({'testCommits.html': linechart})
```

testCommits.html

```
<head>
    <!-- code to include the highcharts and jQuery libraries goes here -->
    <!-- load_charts filter takes a comma-separated list of id's where -->
    <!-- the charts need to be rendered to                             -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    {% load chartit %}
    {{ linechart|load_charts:"container" }}
</head>
<body>
    <div id='container'> Chart will be rendered here </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you map your view in `urls.py`? Try to see if you can access your view with your browser.

Comment: Yes,  url(r'^lineChart/', dashboard.views.lineChart),

Comment: I know it is hitting the def in the view because I can see the error in the stack trace when it loads it in the browser.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem but the return of your view is wrong. Should be `return render_to_response('testCommits.html', linechart)`

Comment: Based on the guideline, that is incorrect and causes a syntax error.

Comment: Ok my bad. Didn't know you could pass it as a dictionary as well.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in their installation instructions they don't say to add 'chartit' to the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file,  but they did in their demo project. Have you done that?

Edit:
dan-klasson is correct. You need to specify the template to return. Your view should be returning the following:

```
return render_to_response('testCommits.html', {'linechart': linechart})
```

The dictionary is the context in that is passed to the template. The first argument is the template name, which in your case is testCommits.html.

Comment: Is the testCommits.html template in a folder? Are you able to render other template successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your Django does not know the location of your templates during template loading. Try this:

1. Go to your *settings.py* in your project root and specify your *TEMPLATE_DIRS*. The variable is already defined for you so simply list the path_to_your_dir. For example:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
           "home/myname/path_to_templates"
   )
   ```
2. Update your view to return properly as specified by other users:

   ```
   return render_to_response('testCommits.html', {'linechart': linechart})
   ```